# JPA with Google Cloud SQL "NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.prefs.Preferences is a restricted class"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I am using JPA with GAE/Google Cloud SQL, and have set up everything according to the Google documents. I am able to browse my JPA Entities in Eclipse, and the app runs fine, except when I try to do:

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
```

Inside EMF, I do:

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyApp");
```

...and that's what causes the errors.  Is this the right way to acquire the EntityManagerFactory?

Below is the traceback.  I also pasted by persistence.xml contents below the traceback, but it was autogenerated, and I think it is correct.  I don't understand why Preferences is being restricted, since I used Google's recommended way of accessing the EntityManagerFactory.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.prefs.Preferences is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:34)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at org.pathways.myapp.rest.impl.GetProgramNameByID.<init>(GetProgramNameByID.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:238)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

And here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>org.myapp.shared.ProfileInfo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.cloud.sql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://mydomain.net:myapp:mydbinstance/mydb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a conflict with two different jpa providers.

You should remove eclipselink as google app engine uses datanucleus. Check your library dependencies.

Edit:

The correct solution was to change `com.google.cloud.sql.Driver` to `com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver` in persistence.xml

Comment: To clarify: the org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa packages found in your stacktrace should not be on your classpath. If it would have been using datanucleus it would have contained org.datanucleus.api.jpa instead.

Comment: Thanks, but in their tutorial at [link](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools), Google suggests using such as EclipseLink 2.3.x, and doesn't even describe the process for using DataNucleus' JPA with Cloud SQL, though it should be possible.  I think you must be referring to Datanucleus being the only JPA available for the Google Datastore (nosql).  Regardless, I tried your suggestion of removing EclipseLink to see if DataNucleus libs would take over automagically, and I got the same error, albeit without org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa in the traceback.

Comment: oops, in the first sentence, I meant "...Google suggests using EclipseLink 2.3.x..."

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Did you follow this guide? https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools If so, did you verify that you are running "App Engine SDK 1.6.4 or later"?

Comment: Yes, that's the guide I've been using.  I'm using 1.6.5.  The documentation for this really needs to be improved.

Comment: Try changing com.google.cloud.sql.Driver to com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver this is what they use at https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java

Comment: That did help, and I got it to work.  I actually had just created a new project it generated that same string as well.  The JPA started working!  Now, I need to go back and fix the original project. :)

Comment: I gave you the accepted solution, since your comments do contain the solution.