# Using JPA with Google Cloud SQL causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileWriter is a restricted class

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am having problems using JPA on Google Cloud SQL. I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileWriter, a class that is indeed not supported by Google App Engine.

I carefully followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools using EclipseLink 2.4.1 - Juno (I run Eclipse Juno on Linux Mint 14)

I also tried using EclipseLink 2.3.3 - Indigo instead, but with the same results.

I know the Google Cloud SQL database as such is working, as I tried using JDBC access according to this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide
and that worked as expected.

The first method invoking JPA is this:

```
public static void createBookJPA(BookJPA c) 
{
  logger.info("Entering createBookJPA: [" + c.getIsbn() + "," + c.getBookName() + "]");
  EntityManager mgr = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
  try 
  {
    logger.info("before begin");
    mgr.getTransaction().begin();
    logger.info("before persist");
    mgr.persist(c);
    logger.info("before commit");
    mgr.getTransaction().commit();
    logger.info("after commit");
  }
  finally 
  {
    mgr.close();
  }
  logger.info("Exiting createBookJPA");
}
```

Which gives this in the log:

```
feb 15, 2013 2:29:25 PM dk.lundogbendsen.schoubo.gae.ex5demo.BookService createBookJPA
INFO: Entering createBookJPA: [JPA:978-1-849690-44-7,Google App Engine Java and GWT Application Development]

[EL Info]: 2013-02-15 14:29:25.79--ServerSession(619728523)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345
[EL Info]: connection: 2013-02-15 14:29:29.088--ServerSession(619728523)--file:/home/jschoubo/Interests/Softfact/Develop/GAE/eclipseworkspaceGAE/lobGAE/war/WEB-INF/classes/_transactions-optional login successful
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2013-02-15 14:29:30.333--ServerSession(619728523)--java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileWriter is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

feb 15, 2013 2:29:30 PM dk.lundogbendsen.schoubo.gae.ex5demo.LobGAEEx5DemoSQLJPA createAuthor
WARNING: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileWriter is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

I run the code locally in developer mode on the Jetty, but I am using the remote Cloud SQL base as I have no local MySQL installed.

This link [JPA with Google Cloud SQL "NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.prefs.Preferences is a restricted class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001978) seems to talk about a similar problem, but I already checked that my persistence.xml contains com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver, so the solution does not fix my problem...

Any help will be much appreciated!

[EDIT]
A couple of further observations:

- The inclusion of EclipseLink prevents the JDO access to HRD from working - when I try, I get class loader error on javax.jdo.JDOHelper
- Removing the JPA facet and the eclipselink jars in WEB-INF/lib made the NoClassDefFoundError go away and made the code go through all the steps (begin, persist, commit). However, now the records are written to the dev.mode HRD datastore locally (local_db.bin) ? So maybe the question is how I get the DataNucleus JPA to use Cloud SQL ?

Somewhere (I can't find the reference) I stumbled on a remark that EclipseLink is wholly superfluous, as JPA support for Google Cloud SQL (as well as for HRD) is already in the DataNucleus package. Can someone confirm this?